# Transformar las etiquetas para que se muestren tal cual como vienen de la base de datos

Tags: html, vue.js

Traigo información de la bd la cual se almacena con los tags de html,
quisiera mostrar esa información pero que el navegador me interprete las etiquetas porque no lo está haciendo.

La info viene en json y estoy trabajando con laravel 5.8, vue y mysql.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además de ello quiero aprovechar para consultar cómo se llama este efecto de desplazamiento el cual también quiero aplicar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de esta forma se traen los datos en props:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y así los muestro en mi vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra como pintas esa datos en tu vista

Comment: acabo de editar la pregunta para colocar lo que me solicitas

Comment: ya lo intente y no escapa los caracteres!

Comment: Con vue puedes usar la directiva[`v-html`](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#HTML-Puro).

Comment: @Johan debes agregar decode, es decir `{!!html_entity_decode(variable)!!}`

Comment: @AlbertoCastillo, este es el retultado que obtendo:  {!!html_entity_decode(detalle.contenidos.contenido)!!}

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ excelente, este si me funciono muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

creo que la ducumentación lo explica bastante bien, y la pregunta va más de que se desconocía la directiva, así que respondo con lo que dice en la documentación y agrego un snippet ejecutable.

#### [HTML Puro](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#HTML-Puro)

Los *mustaches* (llaves doble) interpretan los datos como texto plano, no HTML. Para generar HTML real, deberá utilizar la directiva `v-html`:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    rawHtml: '<p>El contenido del <code>span</code> se reemplazará con el valor de la propiedad <code>rawHtml</code>, interpretado como HTML simple: se ignoran los enlaces de datos. Tenga en cuenta que no puede utilizar <code>v-html</code> para componer plantillas parciales, porque Vue no es un motor de plantillas basado en cadenas. En cambio, se prefieren los componentes como la unidad fundamental para la reutilización y la composición de la interfaz de usuario.</p>'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p><b>Usando mustaches</b>:</p> <p>{{ rawHtml }}</p>
  <p><b>Usando directiva <code>v-html</code></b>:</p> <span v-html="rawHtml"></span>
</div>
```

El contenido del `span` se reemplazará con el valor de la propiedad `rawHtml`, interpretado como HTML simple: se ignoran los enlaces de datos. Tenga en cuenta que no puede utilizar `v-html` para componer plantillas parciales, porque Vue no es un motor de plantillas basado en cadenas. En cambio, se prefieren los componentes como la unidad fundamental para la reutilización y la composición de la interfaz de usuario.

**NOTA Importante**: La ejecución dinámica de HTML arbitrario en su sitio web puede ser muy peligrosa porque puede conducir fácilmente a vulnerabilidades de XSS. Utilice solo la interpolación HTML en contenido de confianza y nunca en contenido proporcionado por usuario.